# Wordpress Page Update

Tags: wordpress, server

Today, when I tried to update a page in my wordpress website, I encountered the following error:

"This page isn’t working "URL of website" didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

When I checked the error logs at server, I found the following:

[Thu Jan 17 13:20:11 2019] [error] [client 39.98.177.226] client denied by server configuration: /home/clcl1721/public_html/403.shtml
[Thu Jan 17 13:20:11 2019] [error] [client 39.98.177.226] client denied by server configuration: /home/clcl1721/public_html/joomla
[Wed Jan 16 23:08:30 2019] [error] [client 35.195.53.238] client denied by server configuration: /home/clcl1721/public_html/403.shtml
[Wed Jan 16 23:08:30 2019] [error] [client 35.195.53.238] client denied by server configuration: /home/clcl1721/public_html/
[Wed Jan 16 21:51:52 2019] [error] [client 31.184.193.83] client denied by server configuration: /home/clcl1721/public_html/403.shtml
[Wed Jan 16 21:51:52 2019] [error] [client 31.184.193.83] client denied by server configuration: /home/clcl1721/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cherry-plugin/includes/js/cherry-plugin.js
[Wed Jan 16 21:51:52 2019] [error] [client 31.184.193.83] client denied by server configuration: /home/clcl1721/public_html/403.shtml
[Wed Jan 16 21:51:52 2019] [error] [client 31.184.193.83] client denied by server configuration: /home/clcl1721/public_html/

Can somebody please suggest how to rectify this error?

Thank you.

Comment: The error states that there's some configuration on your server that is preventing or blocking you from performing the action of updating the page. If you don't know what it is, I would recommend getting in touch with your hosting provider.

Comment: Why is your WP site generating Joomla errors?